# PHP - how to give path to read pdf?

Tags: javascript, php

Select file name and redirect..

**index.php**

```
<?php
$book_name = ["Jenkins_Essentials","Asterisk","phalcon"];
echo "<select><option selected>Book Name</option>";
foreach ($book_name as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option name='$key'>$value</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").on("change",function(){
        location.href = "reading.php?title="+$(this).val();            

    });
});
</script>
```

**reading.php**

```
$title = $_GET["title"];
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="$title.pdf"');
@readfile('D:\Learning\$title.pdf');//this is my issue
```

When I redirected it show `Failed to load PDF document`..
My running script file location is as we know `C:\xampp\htdocs` But pdf file place is as shown in above `D:` drive !How to give path to it?

Comment: does php have access to that directory?

Comment: Never suppress warning with `@` during debug phase. Remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your last two lines, PHP isn't including the $title variable, as you are using **single quotes** and you are using **backslashes**. Try one of these:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$title.'.pdf"');
@readfile('D:/Learning/'.$title.'.pdf');
```

or:

```
readfile("D:/Learning/$title.pdf");
```

Backslashes are used for escaping characters, so use forward slashes as much as you can. On Windows, you can use both in file paths. Also, for outputting the file, try using this instead of @readfile:

```
$pdf = file_get_contents('D:/Learning/'.$title.'.pdf');
echo $pdf;
```

Another note - you should check if the file exists before accessing it. Place at the top of your script:

```
if(!file_exists('D:/Learning/'.$title.'.pdf')) {
    echo "File doesn't exist.";
    exit();
}
```

Hope this helps. Wish you the best.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Your answer had flaws and didn't completely fix the problem.

Comment: One part of one of three examples had flaws, and the reason for the error I was correct on - Just saying.  Over all improvements to the code style or method are beside the point of actual figuring out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file name `'D:\Learning\$title.pdf'` literally `$title.pdf` with the dollar ($) sign.

PHP variable interpolation works on the `"` double quote meaning that your variable is literally a string and not recognized as a variable by php.

You'll most likely want to change that to

```
 readfile("D:\Learning\$title.pdf");
```

OR ( personally I would avoid this because of the back slash escaping )  However it's worth noting that windows will accept the forward slash ( Unix style )

```
readfile('D:\Learning\\'.$title.'.pdf');
readfile('D:/Learning/'.$title.'.pdf'); //this works fine on windows and avoids escaping the \
```

OR what I prefer.

```
 readfile("D:\Learning\{$title.pdf}");
```

Otherwise it's looking for a file named `$title.pdf` literally

Comment: Your second example is wrong, as you didn't include quotes around the file extension.

Comment: @WilliamCasey - that's true but also the \ backslash was escaping the ' single quote in that example ~ cheers